# php function that returns a select element

Tags: php, html, function, parameters

```
public static function select($name, $options_array, $key_as_value=true, $selected="!NO!")
    {
        $html = "<select name='$name'>\n";

        foreach($options_array as $key => $val)
        {
            $option_value = ($key_as_value) ? $key : $val;
            $option_display = $val;
            $selected = ($selected != "!NO!" && $selected == $option_value) ? " SELECTED" : "";

            $option = "<option value='$option_value'$selected>$option_display</option>\n";
            $html .= $option;
        }

        $html .= "</select>\n";

        return $html;
    }
```

This is my PHP code that generates a SELECT element, if you pass $selected it will have the desired option selected. The problem is, having the default value as "!NO" looks very ugly. But I can't make it as FALSE either because FALSE is synonim for 0 and if there is an option with value "0" it won't work as expected.

Any suggestions for this?

Comment: How about null? You use $selected as both parameter and in-loop variable. Are you sure? What happens if one of the val / option_value is " SELECTED" or blank?

Comment: `FALSE` is not a synonym for `0`. Yes, `0 == FALSE`, but `0` is an `int` and `FALSE` is a `bool`. Therefore `0 !== FALSE`. See the answer by @dkamins for more information.

Comment: I try copying your code to run, are you displaying the val or the key?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `FALSE` as long as you use the triple equal operator `===`.  Here are some good links explaining this:

- [How do the PHP equality (== double equals) and identity (=== triple equals) comparison operators differ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80646/how-do-the-equality-double-equals-and-identity-triple-equals-comparis)
- http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: The OP's decision, not yours, but `null` is probably a more appropriate value.